# Order Woocommerce Products by Latest Reviewed

Tags: shortcode, woocommerce-offtopic

In my Woocommerce site, I have:

```
[recent_products per_page="16" columns="4"]
```

which as the shortcode infers, orders products by the most recent.

If I wanted to order my products by the ones latest reviewed, how would I go about doing that? Would it be as simple as:

```
[recent_products per_page="16" columns="4" orderby="meta_key" ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce includes several options in the core plugin for sorting your products on the Shop page. However, most people don’t realize that there’s actually an option for WooCommerce custom product sorting. By default, you’re given 6 options:

1. Default Sorting (custom + name)
2. Popularity (sales)
3. Average rating
4. Most recent
5. Sort by price (ascending)
6. Sort by price (descending)

Under WooCommerce > Settings > Products, change the “Default Product Sorting” to “Default Setting (custom ordering + name)” and we’ll get going from there.

[image]

Comment: I found the page you copy and pasted that response from: https://www.sellwithwp.com/create-woocommerce-custom-product-sorting/ However, if you read further along, this only activates the drag and drop sorting feature in WooCommerce. I don't want to have to drag and drop each product when it gets a new review. I'd like it to be automatic. So this doesn't help me at all.